# Regex to remove escape slashes in string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string

```
/bus-stops/
```

Can anyone help me with a regex to remove escape slashes and provide only the string?

Comment: What have you tried? If the slashes are always the first and last character, then you don't even need regex...just select the substring that is the second to n-1'th character? (n being the length of the string)

Comment: Which language/program do you want to use to do this?

Comment: What about strings like `/AC\/DC/`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myString.replaceAll("\\/","");`

Comment: He doesn't say anything about language ))

Comment: myString.replaceAll("\\/","");

Comment: Perhaps for completeness you could also post an INTERCAL solution?

Comment: @tripleee, I'm lucky http://thegurglingcod.typepad.com/.a/6a00d8341c387d53ef0148c84decb8970c-320wi

Comment: This solution is BETTER even though it doesn't use regexs.  I think the original question is actually probably WRONG anyways.  Does he want to turn `\n` into just 'n'? Is that right in his context? Who can say. But for what he asked, regexs are the wrong approach.

Comment: The forward slashes has no special meaning in regexes, so you don't need to escape it.  But WarrenP is correct: you could just as easily use `.replace("/", "")` and not have to worry about escaping regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=/)[^/]+(?=/)
```

This will match slash delimited characters (without including the slashes)

#### Edit since adding the `java` tag

Here's how to use a simpler regex in java:

```
String input = "foo/bus-stops/bar";
String token = input.replaceAll(".*/([^/]+)/.*", "$1");
System.out.println(token); // prints "bus-stops"
```

Comment: Probably the non-greedy variation `(?<=/)[^/]+?(?=/)` is even better

Comment: @jupp0r There is no such thing as a "non greedy" version of this regex - it captures **all** (non-slash) characters between slashes. Your regex would return exactly the same as mine every time.

Comment: @jupp0r: Also, it would be slower because it would lead to a lot of backtracking. Bohemian's version needs 5 steps of the regex engine on the string `/1234567890/`, your version requires 32 (testing with RegexBuddy).

Comment: Yup, sorry. By excluding the slash character you already achieved the same.

Comment: There's no need for lookarounds here; `[^/]+` alone will suffice.  Of course, it will also match strings that don't have slashes at both ends; that shouldn't be a problem since all you're doing is removing the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove your all escape slashes from string

str.replaceAll("\\\\","");